# React useState returns old value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

In the following example I render three items: 1, 2, 3. I click on item 3 to delete it, however what remains on screen is items 2 & 3 instead of only 1 & 2, since item 3 should have been deleted. Why is item 3 not removed ?

Here is a codesandbox link, clicking on 3 should remove it: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-currying-1bxnb?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(data);

  const onDelete = (id) => {

    //LOGGING
    console.log(`^^^^^^^^^^BEFORE DELETING^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`)
    items.forEach( i => console.log(i.title))
    console.log(`-----------------------------------------`)

    //LOGIC
    let filteredItems = items.filter((c) => c.id != id);
    setItems([...filteredItems]);

    //LOGGING
    console.log(`^^^^^^^^^^AFTER DELETING^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`)
    filteredItems.forEach( i => console.log(i.title))
    console.log(`-----------------------------------------`)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((i) => (
        <Item id={i.id} title={i.title} onDelete={onDelete} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const data = [
  {
    id: 3,
    uuid: "dbc74622-7002-41d2-9d89-e3d0d4558d25",
    title: "Item 3"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    uuid: "c7ac4c96-c1e0-45a4-a739-6ca4ad483b68",
    title: "Item 2"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    uuid: "48c90e0b-5b09-4583-8665-1f3d6f9df5f1",
    title: "Item 1"
  }
];

const Item = ({ id, title, onDelete }) => {

  console.log(`Rendering Item ${title}`)
  const [inputTitle, setTitle] = useState(title);
  console.log(`Value set in useState ${inputTitle}`)
  // ^ this is where the problem occurs even though I set "Item 2", this returs "Item 3"

  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        onDelete(id);
      }}
      key={id}
    >
      <h3>{inputTitle}</h3>
    </div>
  );

};
```

Comment: Could you clarify why the order matters ? If i have removed an item from the array it should not be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) prop should go on the `<Item>` component in your `items.map()` callback, not on the `<div>` element which has no siblings. It's necessary so that React can determine which `Item` instance in the virtual DOM is associated with each respective element of your `items` array.

As a side note, you don't need to spread `filteredItems` when calling `setItems()` since the `items.filter()` method already returns a new array instance, so `setItems(filteredItems);` is sufficient.